# Log4j's rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern is also changing name of files that are zipped in

Tags: java, log4j

I have used log4j's rolling policy for compressing files that reach to certain amount in size. Below log4j properties are working properly.

```
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.FILE.rollingPolicy.maxIndex=13
log4j.appender.FILE.triggeringPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
log4j.appender.FILE.triggeringPolicy.MaxFileSize=80
log4j.appender.FILE.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=log/projectlog_${current.date.time}.%i.log.gz
log4j.appender.FILE.rollingPolicy.ActiveFileName=log/project_log_${current.date.time}.log
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n
```

But problem here is after it generates a compressed file, it also renames the file which is present in the compressed gz file with the name of gz file.

For my scenario, I don't want log4j to rename file that is present in the compressed gz archive. Is there any way by which we can restrict log4j to not to change file names which it is compressing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot with the code provided by log4j @UmarTahir.

As you can see in the [source code](https://apache.googlesource.com/log4j-extras/+/refs/heads/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j/rolling/FixedWindowRollingPolicy.java) of the `FixedWindowRollingPolicy`class, in the method that actually handles the `rollover`, they first instruct `RollingFileAppender` to rename, synchronously, the file, and then compress it, asynchronously, if necessary:

```java
  public RolloverDescription rollover(final String currentFileName) {
  if (maxIndex >= 0) {
    int purgeStart = minIndex;
    if (!explicitActiveFile) {
      purgeStart++;
    }
    if (!purge(purgeStart, maxIndex)) {
      return null;
    }
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    formatFileName(new Integer(purgeStart), buf);
    String renameTo = buf.toString();
    String compressedName = renameTo;
    Action compressAction = null;
    if (renameTo.endsWith(".gz")) {
      renameTo = renameTo.substring(0, renameTo.length() - 3);
      compressAction =
        new GZCompressAction(
          new File(renameTo), new File(compressedName), true);
    } else if (renameTo.endsWith(".zip")) {
      renameTo = renameTo.substring(0, renameTo.length() - 4);
      compressAction =
        new ZipCompressAction(
          new File(renameTo), new File(compressedName), true);
    }
    FileRenameAction renameAction =
      new FileRenameAction(
        new File(currentFileName), new File(renameTo), false);
    return new RolloverDescriptionImpl(
      currentFileName, false, renameAction, compressAction);
  }
  return null;
}
```

The returned `RolloverDescription` will be used in the [`RollingFileAppender`](https://apache.googlesource.com/log4j-extras/+/refs/heads/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j/rolling/RollingFileAppender.java) `rollover` method to handle the actual rollover process:

```java
public boolean rollover() {
  //
  //   can't roll without a policy
  //
  if (rollingPolicy != null) {
    Exception exception = null;
    synchronized (this) {
      //
      //   if a previous async task is still running
      //}
      if (lastRolloverAsyncAction != null) {
        //
        //  block until complete
        //
        lastRolloverAsyncAction.close();
        //
        //    or don't block and return to rollover later
        //
        //if (!lastRolloverAsyncAction.isComplete()) return false;
      }
      try {
        RolloverDescription rollover = rollingPolicy.rollover(getFile());
        if (rollover != null) {
          if (rollover.getActiveFileName().equals(getFile())) {
            closeWriter();
            boolean success = true;
            if (rollover.getSynchronous() != null) {
              success = false;
              try {
                success = rollover.getSynchronous().execute();
              } catch (Exception ex) {
                exception = ex;
              }
            }
            if (success) {
              if (rollover.getAppend()) {
                fileLength = new File(rollover.getActiveFileName()).length();
              } else {
                fileLength = 0;
              }
              if (rollover.getAsynchronous() != null) {
                lastRolloverAsyncAction = rollover.getAsynchronous();
                new Thread(lastRolloverAsyncAction).start();
              }
              setFile(
                rollover.getActiveFileName(), rollover.getAppend(),
                bufferedIO, bufferSize);
            } else {
              setFile(
                rollover.getActiveFileName(), true, bufferedIO, bufferSize);
              if (exception == null) {
                LogLog.warn("Failure in post-close rollover action");
              } else {
                LogLog.warn(
                  "Exception in post-close rollover action", exception);
              }
            }
          } else {
            Writer newWriter =
              createWriter(
                  createFileOutputStream(
                      rollover.getActiveFileName(), rollover.getAppend()));
            closeWriter();
            setFile(rollover.getActiveFileName());
            this.qw = createQuietWriter(newWriter);
            boolean success = true;
            if (rollover.getSynchronous() != null) {
              success = false;
              try {
                success = rollover.getSynchronous().execute();
              } catch (Exception ex) {
                exception = ex;
              }
            }
            if (success) {
              if (rollover.getAppend()) {
                fileLength = new File(rollover.getActiveFileName()).length();
              } else {
                fileLength = 0;
              }
              if (rollover.getAsynchronous() != null) {
                lastRolloverAsyncAction = rollover.getAsynchronous();
                new Thread(lastRolloverAsyncAction).start();
              }
            }
            writeHeader();
          }
          return true;
        }
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        exception = ex;
      }
    }
    if (exception != null) {
      LogLog.warn(
        "Exception during rollover, rollover deferred.", exception);
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

If you need this special behavior, maybe you can create your own rolling policy, and try to implement something similar to what is done in `FixedWindowRollingPolicy`, in a way best fits your requirements, and configure log4j to use this new rolling policy.

That been said, be aware that gzip means just compressing your data, there is no actual filename or file entry, just data compressed. If you use the `gzip` tool, it takes the name of the archive to compress, compress the data, and store the result in a new file with a suffix, typically `.gz`. This is the behavior log4j is trying to mimic in their code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and for sharing the codebase link. I am surprised they tried to do this way.

Comment: You are welcome @UmarTahir.  You are right, although, if you think it carefully, it makes sense: the first, synchronously, do a rename operation, which should be a quick operation, and then, asynchronously, they perform a compress operation, which in terms of time and resource usage could be more costly and with the risk of block the loggers normal operation.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Also in my scenario, since my product has to return the result in 20ms log4j isn't proving beneficial for us as we have a lot of threads. Yesterday I did some benchmarks on log4j/log4j2 to see how much time does 30 thread takes to come back after executing log.info. Mostly Results were in 20ms.

Comment: I think it would have been great if there were a really small number of consumer threads working in underlying logging functionality. Thus avoiding main threads to execute something else.

Comment: It is right @UmarTahir. I think maybe you can try a recent logging framework like logback or log4j2 as you indicated, probably with a SLF4J facade. These frameworks will provide you better performance and I think they are better suited for today's applications.

Comment: I did try log4j2. Surprisingly log4j2 is slow as well for our case. But I can give a try to logback

Comment: Yes, please, give it a try. Also, you can try async loggers in Log4j2: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html. Please, be aware that I only have knowledge of this kind of async loggers, but I actually have not use it in any production project, so I do not how they will perform.

Comment: I tried async logger it is really good as compared to non-sync. But still not suitable for our case. Before handling over the string to the underlying thread main thread performs some other tasks as well. Ideally, the main thread should have given a message to the logger and should have resumed its processing. It is good for 95 % of applications out there but in our case, it is not fulling requirements.

Comment: Thank you for highlighting this I saw its code and observed where I can make improvements for scenarios to make it even faster and reliable :)

Comment: You are welcome @UmarTahir. In fact, thank you, I really appreciate when people takes care of the code to such a deep level, well done.

Comment: I am adding this comment just for future reference If someone encountered the same problem as I did and you decided to rewrite the above functionality as this answer suggested i.e. compressing file without changing the name. For you to add this behavior you need to replace GZOutputStream with apache common GzipCompressorOutputStream and provide GzipParameters in the constructor.

Comment: Apparently log4j and lo4j2 are using GZIPOutputStream which by default changes the name of the compressed file. So the problem here is in GZIPOutputStream as well which should be replaced by GzipCompressorOutputStream in case you guys want to add the above use case. I guess someday log4j log4j2 team can replace this by default.